# Math novice here - What tag should I use for a question about calculating a trend?

Tags: discussion, tagging

That's pretty much it.  I want to calculate a trend of some numbers but I don't know how.  I Asked a question but there is no "trend" tag.

Comment: The tag [tag:data-analysis] could fit.

Comment: It's okay if the tags aren't perfect in something you post.  Others can edit your tags later to make them more accurate.

Comment: So is it like you know $f(1), f(2), f(3)$ and you have a hunch about how to compute $f(4)$?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Indeed, there is no "trend" tag here. But there is a [trend](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trend) tag on Cross Validated, with 153 questions. Consider whether your question would be a better fit there. (Searching existing questions and answers with that tag is a good idea, too.)

On Mathematics site, some of the tags that could fit (no pun intended) are [data-analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-analysis), [data-mining](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-mining), [time-series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time-series), [regression](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regression). And adding the general [statistics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/statistics) tag is highly recommended; questions with only one, very specific tag tend to be overlooked.

Comment: I didn't know about that sub, thanks!